# Unshape and reshape a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of 56 images each with 2 channels for the pixels. Thus its shape is (1200, 800, 52, 2). I need to do a KNeighborsClassifier and it needs to be flattened so that all the pixels in all 52 images are in one column. So shape (1200*800*52,2). Then after the classification is performed - I need to know that I can unshape them in the correct order.

As a first step, I am trying to just unshape and reshape the same array and try to get it to be the same as the original.

Here is what I have tried which doesn't seem to work:

```
In [55]: Y.shape
Out[55]: (1200, 800, 2, 52)

In [56]: k = np.reshape(Y,(1200*800*52,2))

In [57]: k.shape
Out[57]: (49920000, 2)

In [58]: l = np.reshape(k,(1200,800,52,2))

In [59]: l.shape
Out[59]: (1200, 800, 52, 2)

In [60]: assert l == Y
/Users/alex/anaconda2/bin/ipython:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  #!/bin/bash /Users/alex/anaconda2/bin/python.app
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-9faf5e8e20ba> in <module>()
```

Edit: I made an error in k and Y's shapes. here is the corrected version, still with an error though

```
In [78]: Y.shape
Out[78]: (1200, 800, 2, 52)

In [79]: k = np.reshape(Y,(1200*800*52,2))

In [80]: k.shape
Out[80]: (49920000, 2)

In [81]: l = np.reshape(k,(1200,800,2,52))

In [82]: assert Y == l
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-6f6815930213> in <module>()
----> 1 assert Y == l

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `Y` has shape `(1200, 800, 2, 52)`, but `l` has shape `(1200, 800, 52, 2)` the two are not equal because the shapes do not match.

Comment: oops. I have updated the question and the code. A different error occurs, but the reshaping still appears not to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Y == l)` is a boolean array of the same shape as `Y` and `l`.

`assert expression` evaluates `expression` in a boolean context. In other words, `expression.__bool__()` is called.

By design, the `ndarray.__bool__` method raises

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

because it's not clear if `__bool__` should return `True` when *all* the elements are `True`, or when *any* of the elements are `True`.

You can avoid the error by calling either the `all` or `any` method, depending on your intent. In your case you would want to assert that all values are equal:

```
assert (Y == l).all()
```

---

Since comparing floats for equality can sometimes return unexpected results due to the imprecision of floating point arithmetic, comparing floating point arrays for equality can also more safely be done with

```
assert np.allclose(Y, l)
```

Note that [`np.allclose`](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) accepts relative tolerance and absolute tolerance parameters 
to cope with floating-point imprecision.

Comment: This is correct. Id like to add that for my case, Y =  np.transpose(Y,(3,0,1,2)) to make the shape (52,1200,800,2). This makes more intuitive sense to me as 52 cases of 1200 rows of 800 columns of 2 channels each. Then .any, .all, and .allclose all asserted just fine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your error is in line 56, where you use a `reshape` that doesn't follow the original dimensions of `Y` (last axis is 52, but you reshape as it was 2).

Perhaps you should try

```
k = np.reshape(Y,(1200*800*2,52))
```

since it seems to reflect better the idea of having "52 flattened images".

Comment: Well I want flattened pixel values. The "2" is for a and b color channels. I think that would be lost in this case.